# Not sure if feasible: H2:not(:first-line)

Tags: css, transform, pseudo-element

As I mention in the title, I'm not sure whether it's me and my coding-"skills", or just a misfit concept:

Can I change the Lines *after* :first-line of H1 and H2 tags?

This was for an experiment, so not all too important, I wanted to style the titles like my business's logo: the second line is rotated 180°:

`H2:not(:first-line){-webkit-transform: rotate(-18deg);}`

Comment: why don't you give that element a `class="logo"`, so you can do the transform.

Comment: You could wrap each part (the first line, then the rest of it) in separate `span` elements in your HTML, give each one a class, and then style them separately.

Comment: no transforms in a `:first-line` selector https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-line and only simple selectors in a `:not()` http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation so that will never work. You will have to wrap the lines somehow and target them individually

Comment: Thanks, lolka_bolka, Jon, and Pevara. It's exactly what I was afraid to hear :-~ Wrapping would be quite a riddle to me since they're the titles of my wordpress blog's posts.

Answer (score 7):

a colleague of mine had the same question.

So let's say, you have a paragraph of 3 lines.

By doing :

`p:first-line { /* CSS */ }`

You just take in consideration the first line of your paragraph, right ?

---

So, basically, if you write :

```
p { ... } 

p:first-line { ... }
```

The first declaration IS your `:not(:first-line)` :)

Comment: `:not(:first-line)` will not work. see: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/not/

Answer (score -1):

Yes. See if this example works for you.

```
h2:not(:nth-child(1)){-webkit-transform: rotate(-18deg);}
```

Comment: first child is not first line